# Listings are not loading in a SharePoint list

Tags: list

I have a list in SharePoint that is grouped by the first variable.

It is 17 groups in total. Now 3 of the groups are just spinning when I try to retrieve their listings. It is the listings in the same 3 groups every time.

When I am exporting the list to excel or opens it in Power BI, all the listings and data are still there so it seems like it is a retrieving problem in that specific list.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following:

- Try refreshing your SharePoint list.
- Make sure you have the right permissions to edit the list.
- If your list has a lot of items (over 5000), it might load slowly, SharePoint can struggle with lists over 5000 items.
- If you’re syncing the list with OneDrive, check if it’s up-to-date and consider resetting the sync.

Let me know if this helps.